# SQL, how to get all rows that have both values... with joins?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using PHP, Oracle 11g Database. I have these database tables (among others, but those count):

```
CREATE TABLE przystanki (
nazwa VARCHAR(32),
id_przyst INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE trasa (
id_trasa INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE polaczenie (
id_przyst INT REFERENCES przystanki(id_przyst),
id_trasa INT REFERENCES trasa (id_trasa)
);

CREATE TABLE kurs (
odjazd INT,
przyjazd INT,
info CHAR(8) DEFAULT '00000000' NOT NULL,
id_przew INT REFERENCES przewoznik(id_przew),
id_trasa INT REFERENCES trasa(id_trasa),
id_cena INT REFERENCES cennik(id_cena),
id_kurs INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);
```

Now I want to get all rows from `kurs` that have `trasa` that has two `przystanki` specified by the user.

I tried something like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT odjazd, przyjazd, info, id_przew, id_cena, id_kurs, id_trasa, id_przyst, nazwa
FROM kurs
INNER JOIN polaczenie USING (id_trasa)
INNER JOIN trasa USING (id_trasa)
INNER JOIN przystanki USING (id_przyst)
WHERE nazwa='{$a}' OR nazwa='{$b}';
```

But it gives me all those rows that has both $a and $b, those that has $a and not $b, and those that has $b and not $a.

I want to get only those that have BOTH $a and $b at the same time.

I tried some stuff with intersect, but it just won't work at all.

For better understanding user wants to go from bus stop (przystanki) $a to bus stop $b and system should check which routes (trasa) have both $a and $b, then list all rides at all available hours, etc. (kurs).

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a many-to-many join you're running into with the polaczenie table. You either have to use `EXISTS` or you need to have two `JOIN`s to polaczenie. I added a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8a0e7/5/0) example. The code runs there. We can test it more if you add some data to the schema.

Example with two joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  kurs.odjazd,
  kurs.przyjazd,
  kurs.info,
  kurs.id_przew,
  kurs.id_cena,
  kurs.id_kurs,
  kurs.id_trasa,
  pr1.id_przyst,
  pr1.nazwa
FROM kurs
INNER JOIN trasa          ON kurs.id_trasa = trasa.id_trasa       
INNER JOIN polaczenie po1 ON kurs.id_trasa = po1.id_trasa
INNER JOIN polaczenie po2 ON kurs.id_trasa = po2.id_trasa
INNER JOIN przystanki pr1 ON pr1.id_przyst = po1.id_przyst
INNER JOIN przystanki pr2 ON pr2.id_przyst = po2.id_przyst
WHERE pr1.nazwa='{$a}' AND pr2.nazwa='{$b}'
```

Example with exists:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  kurs.odjazd,
  kurs.przyjazd,
  kurs.info,
  kurs.id_przew,
  kurs.id_cena,
  kurs.id_kurs,
  kurs.id_trasa,
  pr1.id_przyst,
  pr1.nazwa
FROM kurs
INNER JOIN trasa          ON kurs.id_trasa = trasa.id_trasa       
INNER JOIN polaczenie po1 ON kurs.id_trasa = po1.id_trasa
INNER JOIN przystanki pr1 ON pr1.id_przyst = po1.id_przyst
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM polaczenie po 
  JOIN przystanki pr ON po.id_przyst = pr.id_przyst
  WHERE po.id_trasa = id_trasa
  AND pr.nazwa='{$a}' 
)
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM polaczenie po 
  JOIN przystanki pr ON po.id_przyst = pr.id_przyst
  WHERE po.id_trasa = id_trasa
  AND pr.nazwa='{$b}' 
)
```

Comment: The second code throws an error:
    `ORA-00904: "NAZWA": invalid identifier
    00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`
After removing nazwa from first `SELECT` it throws the same error for `ID_PRZYST`.

After removing that one too, it throws an error about columns being ambigously defined.

The first code throws the columns ambigously defined too.

Comment: I made some updates and added a SQLFiddle example. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11000/2) - I added some data, and it seems to be working... gonna test it on my whole DB now.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `WHERE nazwa='{$a}' AND nazwa='{$b}'` if you want both $a and $b at the same time. Please try and let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: It just returns black table. :<

Comment: If all you need is "to get all rows from kurs that have trasa that has two przystanki specified by the user" then why are you even joining with table "polaczenie".